# How to set opacity for options in select using javascript and css?

Tags: javascript, css

Why doesn't this work for the options of a select too?

```
var x = document.getElementById(id);
x.style.opacity = 0.4;
x.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + 40 + ')';
```

Is there any other way to set the opacity of the entire select?

Comment: Native forms element are a mess to style. I'm afraid setting the opacity of the options item is not possible. You probably should look for replacements using jquery or any other library. There are plenty of them available.

Comment: could you give me an example? i really need to make those options invisible somehow

Comment: Try Eric Hynd's jQuery Multiselect:  http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Comment: here is the thing: i have a select; if i focus it..the options appear. exactly above this select i have a menu which expands on hover. the problem is that when i hover the menu, the options appear above the menu. i need to make the options dissapear. i cannot user hide() because this removes the space that used to be occupied by the select and i don't want this

Comment: Have you tried, applying z-index in dropdown CSS?

Comment: z-index doesn't work for the options...whatever i do, the options would still be displayed above everything else

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help.

**HTML**

```
<select name="test" id="test">
  <option value="test1">test1</option>
  <option value="test2">test2</option>
  <option value="test3">test3</option>
</select>
```

**Style**

```
.optioncolor { color:#999999; opacity:0.5; -moz-opacity:0.5; -webkit-opacity:0.5;}
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#test").find("option").eq(2).addClass("optioncolor");
```

It works in Mozilla. But for webkit u can apply color change, so it looks light. Nothing else can be done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go buddy.

You can either add a class to each of the  elements or just set the css of all  elements

[HERES](http://jsfiddle.net/sHnA6/3/) an example

Comment: Im using firefox 9.0.1. You will have to set the opacity settings for ie and webkit in the css and make sure to change them all in jquery too

Comment: "simply setting the filter/opacity value in IE isn’t enough. Turns out that IE requires an element to be positioned in order for filter/opacity to work. If your element doesn’t have a position you can work around this by adding ‘zoom: 1‘ to your CSS." - http://joseph.randomnetworks.com